# WiX - upgrade services

Tags: wix, installation

I Installed my application in 1.0.0.0 version. Services have been installed on the user account (with username / password).

How to make an update, so the user does not have to specify login and password again?

```
<MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />

      <Component Id="MyService" Guid="MyGUID" Win64="yes">
        <File Id="FileID" Name="MyService.exe" Source="Path\MyService.exe" KeyPath="yes" />
      
        <ServiceInstall Id="InstallService"
                        Type="ownProcess"
                        Name="SERVICENAME"
                        DisplayName="XXX"
                        Description="XXX XXX"
                        Account="NT SERVICE\XXXACCOUNT"
                        ErrorControl="normal"
                        Start="auto" />
      
        <ServiceControl Id="Controlervice" Name="SERVICENAME" Start="install" Stop="both" Remove="uninstall" Wait="yes" />
      </Component>
```

I tried:

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
    <!-- Without overwriting the service configuration -->
    <DeleteServices>NOT UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE</DeleteServices> 
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

But is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That condition is incorrect if you are using it in your upgrade setup. UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE is set in the older already installed product that is being replaced and uninstalled, NOT in the new incoming upgrade. For that you need the property from the upgrade element, WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED if you use the MajorUpgrade Element. However...

It's too late to affect the uninstall of that older product (while it's being upgraded) because its DeleteServices is already in there in the uninstall, ready to happen, and you can't prevent it from happening from inside your new upgrade install. There would be a chance of it working if you had the DeleteServices condition in that older install so that it wouldn't delete as part of its upgrade uninstall. People typically don't do this if there is more than one service because it affects all services.

In general, people do this by saving and encrypting the credentials somewhere so that they can be restored into properties that have the account name and password, so they are recovered on an upgrade, patch, repair etc. If you haven't saved them it's probably too late to fix it now. For example, what happens if you do a repair on the older installed product? Does it ask for the credentials again or does it fail? Or maybe restore the service to run with a default account?

Long term, storing those credentials somewhere is the approach that people take, and the Win32 CredWrite and CredRead and managed code equivalents are more secure than the registry.

I don't think there is a solution for you as given the posted info. If I understand correctly, then that old uninstall will unconditionally call DeleteServices, and you can't prevent that deletion unless you update that old product (such as with a patch) to prevent DeleteServices. And then in the incoming upgrade you'd need to skip calling InstallServices. AND be completely sure that the service binary will be in the exact same location (probably not the browseable application directory!) because you don't want the service settings created by the older install to refer to a binary that the upgrade might install to a different location.